# Flask-Mobility failing with Gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I am using `Flask-Mobility` to render different templates based on the browser.

Everything worked fine on my local machine, but on the server, I get `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'MOBILE'` I am using `gunicorn`.

When I test the app by running it only as a python instance, with no gunicorn and no workers, etc, it works just fine. I see that Flask-Mobility does a `@app.before_request` I am guessing that this isn't being processed when I use Gunicorn.

The line that fails is this:

```
if request.MOBILE == True:
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
ERROR in app: Exception on /content/3/intro-to-genetics-1/1/baby-ball [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_mobility/decorators.py", line 35, in wrapper
     return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "app/main/views.py", line 333, in direct_screen_nav
    if request.MOBILE == True:
File "virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'MOBILE'
```

Comment: Can you add your full traceback ?

Comment: Can you add your related code piece?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what was wrong. The issue wasn't with gunicorn, it was with using Blueprints. I modified `Flask-Mobility`'s `Mobility` `__init__` function to take as an optional argument any Blueprint and added this to `def init_app()`:

```
if blueprint is not None:
    @blueprint.before_app_request
    def before_app_request():
        ctx = stack.top
        if ctx is not None and hasattr(ctx, 'request'):
            self.process_request(ctx.request)
```

So, instead of initialising the library as `Mobility(app)`, I initialise with `Mobility(app, blueprint)` and everything works fine. Not entirely sure why it was working without gunicorn before, but, it likely is because I was using the same name `app` in two different contexts and by happenstance, it worked.